# Committed folders pushed to heroku don't make it

Tags: node.js, angularjs, git, heroku, gitignore

I'm having a weird issue when pushing my app to heroku.
It's an `angularjs` front app with a basic nodejs server to be able to run it on heroku.

I'm pushing a deployment branch with all the app already "compile" by grunt in a `/dist` folder

My problem is in the `/dist/public` directory, I have 4 folders : `js`, `css`, `img` and `fonts` ; but after a push and checking on the dyno with `heroku run bash`, only the `img` one is in `/dist/public`, the 3 others aren't there.

I try to do a new push, renaming the `public` folder to another name (ie `shared`) and this time, all 4 folders are there, so it seems heroku's doing something with folders named *public* but I can't figure why and how to avoid this suppression/ignoring thing.

Has any of you encountered the same issue, and how to resolve it without having to rename my public folder ?

**EDIT :**

Adding my `.gitignore` file for those of you wondering about that:

```
/.vagrant/machines
/node_modules
/app/bower_components
/.sass-cache
/test
/app/src/lib/config.js
/dist
```

Comment: Is there anything in the folders or are the ones not 'making it' empty?  If they are empty, just add a file called `.gitkeep` in each one and it will keep the empty folder structure.

Comment: nope, there are all with files. That's the point, my app's missing all the needed files to work...

Comment: @Sylver Check your `.gitignore` file, you might be having some ignore rules specific to `/dist/public/` folders.

Comment: Hey @mu無, I've added my .gitignore file content to the post. As you see nothing related to /dist/public. I ignore /dist for the master branch but during the deployment, a specific branch is forked and /dist folder is force commited. Everything works as expected and the /dist folder with its content is commited and pushed but the /dist/public/ folders.

Comment: @Sylver I missed this earlier, what is the exact command you run to force add the `/dist` folder? It looks like, your master branch doesn't keep track of the `/dist/public/js` folders, and if there is some issue with the forced adding, than the forked branch won't get updated properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `git add -f dist/public/js dist/public/css dist/public/fonts` from within your repo.

You have a `.gitignore` rule for `/dist`, which will ignore any files within `/dist` and its subdirectories, unless they are already being tracked. My guess is, that the files you have newly generated were not being tracked earlier, and hence they were silently ignored.

The `-f` flag in the git add above will add those forcefully (overriding the ignore rule), and so you will be able to make commits.

If there are only a few files, and you want to avoid adding the whole folders, I would suggest adding each of the individual files forcefully (i.e., with the `-f` flag).

Comment: I knew that and added all the /dist folder with a git add -f, everything else in it is already pushed. But it seems you're right and I have to add these 3 again. I don't understand why only these ones... Anyway thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Sylver as I commented [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456288/committed-folders-pushed-to-heroku-dont-make-it/25459061#comment39728189_25456288), I think the problem was with the adding part. If you are using a script, check the forced add command there. My hunch is you are doing a `git add -f /dist` instead of `git add -f dist`, which wouldn't work on unix style shells.

Comment: @Sylver FWIW, in your `.gitignore`, you don't need to begin the ignore rules with a `/`

Comment: I know. I think I've taken the habit to add it because else it can matches everywhere in the subdirectories, and that's not what I want.