# Error path not found in heroku

Tags: heroku, bootstrap.min.css

I am trying to upload a web to heroku but I get this error:

Error: Path /app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css not found!

In local it works correctly!

What can I do?

Comment: The problem was I had in the .gitignore file the bower_components folder. When I upload the file bootstrap.min.css with git add -f option the problem was solve.

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer so that it is easier for future people with the same problem to understand...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Committed folders pushed to heroku don't make it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456288/committed-folders-pushed-to-heroku-dont-make-it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had in the .gitignore file the bower_components folder. When I upload the file bootstrap.min.css with git add -f option the problem was solve.